# Jasmine Unit Test for to check activate route has two parameters and call service function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a function in my component to get current route parameters and call a function in a service if two parameters are present.

Component.ts:

```
listenToRouteParameters(): void {
    const state = this.route.snapshot?.queryParamMap.get('state');
    const code = this.route.snapshot?.queryParamMap.get('code');
    if (state && code) {
      const codeVerifier = this.cookieService.getCookieValue(state);
      if (codeVerifier) {
        this.cookieService.removeCookie();
        this.initiateTokenExchange(code, codeVerifier);
      } else {
        this.refreshTokens();
      }
    } else {
      this.refreshTokens();
    }
```

}

I wrote a unit test for it as follows.

```
let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let el: HTMLElement;
  let router: Router;
  let route: ActivatedRoute;
  let cookieService: CookieService;
  const paramsSubject = new BehaviorSubject({
    state: '323232323',
    code: '232323232',
  });

beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers:[
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            params: paramsSubject
          },
        },
        { provide: CookieService, useValue: cookieService}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    router = TestBed.get(Router)
    route = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute)
  });

  it('should retrieve cookie if current route has state and code params', () => {
    const activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ActivatedRoute);

    activatedRoute.queryParams = of({ state: '123' });

    fixture.detectChanges(); 
    //  tick();

    activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((value) => {
      expect(cookieService.getCookieValue).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
  });
```

This unit test pass regardless of passing parameters or not. Appreciate it if anyone can have a look and tell me how to properly write unit tests for the scenario.

Edit:
CookieService.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CookieService {

  constructor() { }

  /**
   * Set cookie
   * @param state State value
   * @param codeVerifier Code verifier value
   */
  setCookie(state: string, codeVerifier: string): void {
    document.cookie = `app.txs.${state}=${codeVerifier};secure;sameSite=strict;`;
  }

  /**
   * Get cookie value
   * @param state 
   * @returns 
   */
  getCookieValue(state: string | null): string | undefined {
    return document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith(`app.txs.${state}=`))?.split('=')[1];
  }

  /**
   * Remove cookie
   */
  removeCookie(): void {
    let cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){   
      let spcook =  cookies[i].split("=");
      document.cookie = spcook[0] + "=;expires=Thu, 21 Sep 1979 00:00:01 UTC;";                                
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, follow the comments with !!:

```
// !! change the declaration to this !!
let cookieService: jasmine.SpyObj<CookieService>;
beforeEach(async () => {
    // !! add this !!
    // !! the 2nd argument accepts an array of strings that will
    // mock the public methods as spies !!
    cookieService = jasmine.createSpyObj('CookieService', ['getCookieValue', 'removeCookie']);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers:[
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            params: paramsSubject,
            // mock snapshot as well
            snapshot: {
              queryParamMap: {
                 get: () => {}
              }
            }
          },
        },
        { provide: CookieService, useValue: cookieService}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  
  it('should retrieve cookie if current route has state and code params', () => {
    // !! you don't need this line, you already have a handle on activatedRoute
    // with route = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute)
    // const activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ActivatedRoute);

    spyOn(route.snapshot.queryParamMap, 'get').and.callFake(param => {
       // !! mock however you wish
       if (param === 'code') {
          return 1;
       } else if (param === 'state') {
          return 2;
       }
    });

    fixture.detectChanges(); 
    
    // !! if listenToRouteParameters is called in the ngOnInit
    // then you won't have to explicitly call it because the first fixture.detectChanges()
    // above calls ngOnInit
    component.listenToRouteParameters();
    
    // !! make your expectation
    expect(cookieService.getCookieValue).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: I don't understand how to mock to check the activated URL has both code and state params and why we return 1 and 2 inside if condition. Also, I'm getting this error -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCookieValue'). Could you kindly describe this in detail.

Comment: I think that issue is with `cookieService`. Can you show that in your question? I will explain once I understand.

Comment: I have updated the question with CookieService.

Comment: Oh, I was talking about the mocked `cookieService` (useValue: cookieService), this one.

Comment: I have added it above the beforeEach now.

Comment: Check out my edit with !!. You need to mock all external dependencies and ensure they return accurate values. Check out this resource: https://testing-angular.com/testing-components-depending-on-services/#testing-components-depending-on-services.

Comment: This worked, but I had to put a third 'else' condition which returns an empty or null string.